Stability analysis from S-Parameter / Y-Parameter
I have a netlist from which I have contained the S and Y-Parameters of my circuit. Now I need to analyse my circuit for passivity and stability. Normally, I would use the transfer function to do this. However, I don't know how to approach this from the Y-Parameter and have not found something that worked on the web when you solely have the Y-Parameters.
Does anyone have any ideas on how to approach this? This is a very big circuit and my Parameter-Array is massive, so any ideas I found on the web have not worked at all.
Thank you so much for any help!

Rollet Stability Factor and the $\mu$ test are your friends.

Thank you, but the network is a four-port so the k-factor sadly doesn't work

Please mention these kinds of details in your question. Also, is this a distributed network? Lumped? In feedback? Openloop? Stable to begin with? and so on.
